# Migrating React-router client-side routing to production environment

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, render.com

Whenever I try to visit a URL with an endpoint e.g. `"/product/details/20"`, I get a not found as a response. I found solutions related to this topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928372/react-router-urls-dont-work-when-refreshing-or-writing-manually?page=2&tab=scoredesc#tab-top) but they're not working for me. I'm hosting my project's back-end on a web server using `render.com`. The project folder is divided into 2 folders, client and server. The server folder is the entry point of the web server. I tried the below code after all the API endpoints I provided in server.js but it doesn't seem to work, I'm not even getting the console.log inside the catch-all block.

```js
const clientPath = path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'client', 'build')

// Serve static files from the build directory
app.use(express.static(clientPath))

// Catch-all route handler
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  console.log('in catch-all')
  res.sendFile(path.join(clientPath, 'index.html'))
})
```

Comment: The problem must come from the routing configuration at render.com level and not at application level